# (Windows 10 64 bits) Py to Exe Error Python 3.8 (Pyinstaller, cx_Freeze)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

Hi I'am a new python user please excuse my python basic level.

I have to update 26/10/2020 the Title to Windows 10 64bits, do to the fact that I have done the downgrade to 3.7 and the error is the same. The EXE file just blinks and closes.

I simplify the code to just the screen, using only the frame, and the same result, EXE just blinks and closes.

I think that the error is related to Pyinstaller and Windows 10 64 bits problems.

I am trying to create an EXE file from Py using Pyhton 3.8 unsuccessfully, using pyinstaller and/or cx_Freeze getting the same errors.

Several errors related to the .png, .ico access and even deleting this from the code, a simple screen with a frame does not open.

Please somebody can help me to solve this.

This is the code, I need to create onefile .exe using .PNG as Background and .ICO on the screen not only as .exe file icon.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

#set windows size
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("925x722")

#set title
root.title("SOFT1)")

#frame 1
f1=Frame(root, width=345,height=475,bg="light 
grey",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=4)
f1.place(x=20,y=235)

#set a image as BG
Logo=PhotoImage(file="fileIMG.png")
lab6=Label(root, image=Logo)
lab6.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation such as https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html - look for adding data files to the bundle, and Finding out why your (gui) application won’t start.

Answer (score 0):

Currently python 3.8 isn't supported by pyinstaller. I believe cx_Freeze does, but if you don't need any specific feature from python 3.8 then I would downgrade to python 3.7 and try using pyinstaller again. Simpler that way.

There aren't any specific errors for me to base my answer off of, but I'll show you my usual approach to fixing pyinstaller issues. First, I would run the pyinstaller command with the option --debug=all. By using this option, you can see all that goes on behind the scenes when you try and run your program. Then try running the .exe file from the command line, and redirect standard error to a text file:

```
>your_program_here.exe 2> error.txt
```

If you look inside error.txt, you should see a lot of information. The most important thing to look for is a program trace-back. It's the same kind of trace-back you'll see when there's an error in the python program you're running. the trace-back will show you which line in your code is raising an error, which is usually the culprit of why your .exe won't work.

Looking from your code, I would try using absolute file paths to open your images. Right now you have it so Pet_toolShare.png is opened from the same folder that your python file
is run from. Pyinstaller places the .exe in the "dist" folder so it wouldn't be able to access any files from outside of it unless you place the .exe in the same folder as your images.

Comment: Thanks, I did the 3.7 downgrade and the error is the same, always said: tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "file.png": no such file or directory                  [51132] Failed to execute script FILE

Comment: Checking the debug screen, the error is the same always .PNG defined as background is not loaded and could not open. Even with Python 3.7.

Comment: @TheKraken could you update your question with the exact errors you're facing? ie. The trace-back

Comment: I have to update 26/10/2020 the Title to Windows 10 64bits, do to the fact that I have done the downgrade to 3.7 and the error is the same. The EXE file just blinks and closes.

I simplify the code to just the screen, using only the frame, and the same result, EXE just blinks and closes.

I think that the error is related to Pyinstaller and Windows 10 64 bits problems.

Comment: @TheKraken I managed to get it working on my PC, using Windows 8. I realized you don't have the line "root.mainloop()" at the bottom of your code, which is required for tkinter to run. I added this line in, built into a .exe using pyinstaller, and then moved the exe file from the "dist" folder back up to the main folder so it could access the image. Have you tried all those steps?

Comment: Jasper thanks, the downgrade to 3.7 and the use of root.mainloop() fix the problem. Also before I have been installed Windows SDK and Framework update. Now I need to have embedded the icon and background PNG files into the EXE, that it is possible? in order to distribute only te EXE. By the way the opening is very slow, any suggestion to do it faster?

Comment: @TheKraken should be able to embbed both png and icon in your program, yes. If you can do it in your program, it can be transferred over to the executable. And I'm not sure how to improve start up speed, I have the same issue as well. There's other questions on this website that ask about this, so I would check there.

Comment: Thank Jasper, How can embed the background and icon in only one EXE. The file generated requires both PNG files together in the same folder of the EXE generated by Pyinstaller. Do you have any idea about how to do it, all in one EXE file???

Comment: @TheKraken use complete file paths to locate the image, instead of relying that they both be in the same folder.

Comment: Jasper actually I did it, using the full path still requiring the distribution of the additional (PNG and ICO) files with the EXE file. Thanks for your help I will create a post for this issue specifically.